# Framework for Develop apps

Tags: dapp-development

I know that exist a frameworks for only develop Dapps and are specially focused in the blockchain development. For example: [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle), [Embark](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework), etc.

But my question is if is good or not develop dapps with other frameworks (baseds on node.js), who actually are used for develop normal apps, but using the web3js API  for interact with the ethereum blockchain. For example using: [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/), [Koa.js](http://koajs.com/), etc.

Any one have experience with this? Some tip or recomendation?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Basically, you can write dapps with whatever framework you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience Truffle, Embark, Populus are more like tools that make it easy to deal with contracts programming, deployment and testing. They allow integration with other frameworks for the backend/frontend.